# Character encoding of file names with autoindex at webserver on windows

Tags: windows, nginx, encoding

I have set up a webserver on windows 8.1. Now i am having problems with the character encodings of links: There are directories and file names containing german umlauts (ä ö ü ß). The autoindex feature of the webserver generates index pages for the directories that display the umlauts correctly, but replaces the umlauts with surrogates within the links: ü -> %fc and ö -> %f6 . As a result, the linked file is not found. Nor is it found if i type ü manually instead of %fc

Any Suggestion?

webserver: nginx 1.5.10

charset code in nginx.conf: charset iso-8859-1;

os: windows 8.1 (same box for server and client)

browser: chrome and ie